# Is it possible for an eigenspace to have more than one vector in its basis? What would that imply? Would every vector in the basis be an eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So far I've been seeing that the vector that makes up a basis for the null space of the matrix $A-Ix$ (where x is an eigenvalue) is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $x$. But I've never run into a situation where the basis had more than one vector in it.

Let's say the basis of the null space of $A-2*I$ was made up of two vectors. Would that mean those two (and *only* those two) vectors are the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$ for the matrix $A$?

One thing of note is that, from what I understand, the identity transformation (in any space) has only one eigenvalue, $1$, but it has infinitely many eigenvectors (not sure if there is a vector space where this wouldn't be true, but it's true for $R^n$ at least). Not sure how this fact fits in here.

Just wanting to be sure I'm not misunderstanding something. I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: _Every_ nonzero vector in an eigenspace is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, you can have several vectors in the basis of an eigenspace.

First, when you have only one vector $v$ in a basis for a matrix $A$, with eigenvalue $\mu$, then any multiple of this vector is in the basis : 
$$ \forall c \in \mathbb{R}, \ A(cv)=\mu(cv)$$

Then if you have two vectors in a basis, $v$ and $w$, any linear combination of these two vector will be an eigenvector for $\mu$:
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
Av=\mu v\\
Aw=\mu w\\
\end{array} \right. \Rightarrow A(cv+dw) = \mu (cv+dw)$$

For exemple, let $A=J-I$ a matrix $n\times n$ of all 1, except 0 in the diagonal (this exemple comes from graph theory and the complete graph $K_n$). Then $A$ has eigenvalues $n-1$ and $-1$, and while the eigenspace associated with $n-1$ has dimension $1$ (there is only 1 vector in its basis), the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $-1$ has dimension $n-1$. Hence you can find an orthogonal basis of $n-1$ vectors. Any vector $v$ verifying $Av=-v$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in this basis.

Answer (score 1):

You are understanding things just right.

For example, the $3 \times 3$ matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has two eigenvalues, $2$ and $3$.

Every nonzero vector on the $x$-axis is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $2$, and a basis for that eigenspace.

Every nonzero vector in the $y$-$z$ plane is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $2$. Any two linearly independent vectors in that plane form a basis of eigenvectors for that eigenvalue.